# jQuery on click append class to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Within my `on` click function how can I make it so that my div `#complete-tick` has an css class of `display:block;`?

**Code:**

```
 $('[data-popup-complete]').on('click', function(e)  {
    var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-complete');
    $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);
    $('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').css({ display: "block" });

    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Should be `.css({ 'display': 'block' });`

Comment: @JessMcKenzie, What exactly the problem is?

Comment: What's wrong with `$("#complete-tick").css({'display' : 'block'});`?

Comment: Your doubt is about jQuery class handling? How the lib can do add it to a DOM Node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
 $('[data-popup-complete]').on('click', function(e)  {
var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-complete');
$('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').fadeOut(350);
$('[data-popup="' + targeted_popup_class + '"]').css('display', 'block');

e.preventDefault();
```

});